# Is it still efficient to use the Hungarian algorithm for large values of n?

Tags: algorithm

By large values of n, I mean >100.

Would the Hungarian algorithm still be effective in this usecase or should I use min cost flow for this assignment problem.

Comment: Where the breaking point for any pair of algorithms is will always heavily depend on what implementation you have (specifically, the relative speed per cycle). E.g. for O(n^4) at one second per cycle and O(n) at one year per cycle, it takes quite a bit of elements for the former to become slower. There is no way to know except to benchmark the specific implementations you are using.

Comment: @lurker: no, this is a polynomial complexity.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yep, sorry, I used the incorrect term.